# Hibernate Envers query Audit table with custom query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate Envers to audit entities. There is this possibility to get all versions / revisions of an entity like this:

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(
                Soup.class, true, true);
        auditQuery.add(AuditEntity.property("id").eq(id));
        List<Soup> from = auditQuery.getResultList();
```

But this takes too much time, because it joins all table together (in this example rev, soup_aud, ingredients_aud). And I only need the values from Soup_AUD.

How can I select the values from an audited table with an custom query?

Soup.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOUP")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Wither
@Audited
public class Soup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INGREDIENT_ID")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

}
```

Ingredient.java:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Wither
@Audited
public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspec the reason the join happens is due to the nature of `@OneToMany` being the owning side of the relationship rather than the inverse side.  If you can't modify your mappings then unfortunately I don't believe there is a way to avoid the join presently.

What I could see being addded to support this would be

- Expand `traverseRelation` for `RevisionsOfEntityQuery` types
- Provide a `setFetchMode` method on `AuditQuery` that mirrors its `Criteria` API counterpart.

All of these would be enhancements to Envers; of which contributions would be welcomed.  The first element already has a feature request logged as [HHH-13817](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-13817?filter=allopenissues).  I have also logged [HHH-13818](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13818) for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

My solution now is a nativeQuery from a JPA repository.